# Plot dictionary with multiple values in different colors

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, colors

Is there a way to plot a dictionary with multiple values with different colors? Let's say we have a dictionary:

```
d = {"alpha": [1,2,3,4], "beta": [5,6,7,8]}
```

How could one plot `alpha[0]`, `beta[0]` ... blue and `alpha[1]`, `beta[1]` .... yellow etc?

Let's say that the values are on y-axis and the keys on the x-axis.
My code would look like this:

```
x_multi = []
y_multi = []
for k, v in data_all_bands.iteritems():
    x_multi.extend(list(itertools.repeat(int(k[-3:]), len(v))))
    y_multi.extend(v)

plt_multi = axes[0].scatter(x_multi, y_multi)
```

where data_all_bands looks like this:

```
2016050 [4.2958281793198241, 3.7025449821599157, 5.1717757645735025, 4.9954723025001719]
2016178 [4.0679016016577032, 2.890807214158575, 4.9627629940324081, 4.8505350289087952]
2016290 [3.6947496139720259, 3.1549071645707891, 4.5131724769284824, 4.4082219917836483]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one way using a list of pre-assigned colors of your choice and plotting the values of each key in a different color. This way you don't need to define any empty lists `x_multi` and `y_multi`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
colors = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']
i = 0
for k, v in data_all_bands.items():
    x_multi = list(itertools.repeat(int(k[-3:]), len(v)))
    plt_multi = ax.scatter(x_multi, v, color=colors[i])
    i += 1
```

[image]

**Way 2** since it is unclear what order of colors you want

```
x_multi = [int(k[-3:]) for k in data_all_bands.keys()] 
colors = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']

for i in range(len(list(data_all_bands.values())[0])):
    y_multi = [v[i] for v in data_all_bands.values()]
    plt_multi = ax.scatter(x_multi, y_multi, color=colors[i])
```

[image]

Comment: that's an interesting solution thank you! Even though i can see the correct solution from your approach, maybe you could change the coloring so that alpha[0], beta[0], gamma[0] are blue and alpha[1], beta[1], gamma[1] are yellow etc. This way it would answer my question and i xould mark it as the solution :)

Comment: But they are blue, yellow etc. right now in my solution. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're right sorry! i need to change my question... i expected a different outcome  :) All alphas yellow, all betas blue etc. Sorry for that. You were right

Comment: So does my solution answers your problem?

Comment: yes it did. But now i changed the question...I just could have left it at it is and mark yours as correct though....

Comment: I don't understand. The coloring scheme in my solution is correct or not? Do you want me to change it? I have the other solution now as well

Comment: I would need this: All alphas yellow, all betas blue etc

Comment: So that is what my solution is doing. All alphas are blue, all betas are yellow, all gammas are green. You can switch blue and yellow but it's the same thing

Comment: Ok, I added both answers. Choose whichever you like